# Select elements of numpy array via boolean mask array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, boolean, mask

I have a boolean mask array `a` of length `n`:

```
a = np.array([True, True, True, False, False])
```

I have a 2d array with `n` columns:

```
b = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5]])
```

I want a new array which contains only the "True"-values, for example

```
c = ([[1,2,3], [1,2,3]])
```

`c = a * b` does not work because it contains also "0" for the false columns what I don't want

```
c = np.delete(b, a, 1) does not work
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 75):

You probably want something like this:

```
>>> a = np.array([True, True, True, False, False])
>>> b = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5]])
>>> b[:,a]
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Note that for this kind of indexing to work, it needs to be an `ndarray`, like you were using, not a `list`, or it'll interpret the `False` and `True` as `0` and `1` and give you those columns:

```
>>> b[:,[True, True, True, False, False]]   
array([[2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: I've used this solution and it works well! But on scaling up to a `ndarray` of shape `(2800000,600)`, trying to use a mask with `200` `True` values is slow. Are there any optimisations?

Comment: 2.8M? Normally I would suggest just in time compiling - http://numba.pydata.org/ - not actually sure it will help here.

Comment: Try `numpy.compress` (for bools) or `numpy.take` (for indices), see https://stackoverflow.com/q/46041811/882436

Comment: I did calculate the mask and had to cast the mask to type `np.bool`. So I  added `b[:,a.astype(np.bool)]`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `numpy.ma` module and use `np.ma.masked_array` function to do so.

```py
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 3, -1, 5])                                                
>>> mx = ma.masked_array(x, mask=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
masked_array(data=[1, 2, 3, --, 5], mask=[False, False,  False, True, False], fill_value=999999)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm not too late! Here's your array:

```
X = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
              [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

Let's create an array of zeros of the same shape as `X`:

```
mask = np.zeros_like(X)
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Then, specify the columns that you want to mask out or hide with a `1`. In this case, we want the last 2 columns to be masked out.

```
mask[:, -2:] = 1
# array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
#        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Create a masked array:

```
X_masked = np.ma.masked_array(X, mask)
# masked_array(data=[[1, 2, 3, --, --],
#                    [1, 2, 3, --, --]],
#              mask=[[False, False, False,  True,  True],
#                    [False, False, False,  True,  True]],
#              fill_value=999999)
```

We can then do whatever we want with `X_masked`, like taking the sum of each column (along `axis=0`):

```
np.sum(X_masked, axis=0)
# masked_array(data=[2, 4, 6, --, --],
#              mask=[False, False],
#              fill_value=1e+20)
```

Great thing about this is that `X_masked` is just a view of `X`, not a copy.

```
X_masked.base is X
# True
```