# The efficient way of Array transformation by using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

How to change the ARRAY U(Nz,Ny, Nx) to U(Nx,Ny, Nz) by using numpy? thanks

Answer (score 5):

Just `numpy.transpose(U)` or `U.T`.

Comment: you might need a copy if you want more than just a view

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you want to change the order of data in numpy array, see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html#rearranging-elements.

The `np.fliplr()` and `np.flipud()` functions can be particularly useful when the transpose is not actually what you want.

Additionally, more general element reordering can be done by creating an index mask, partially explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984102/select-elements-of-numpy-array-via-boolean-mask-array)