# mask columns in numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, mask

What is the most efficient way to mask columns from a numpy array?

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape((3,4))
mask = [True False True False]
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
b = a[mask, axis=1]
```

which would give the output:

```
b = [[0, 2],[4, 6], [8, 10]]
```

I need this for a large array.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select elements of numpy array via boolean mask array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984102/select-elements-of-numpy-array-via-boolean-mask-array)

Comment: a short answer `b = a[:, mask]`