# Exchange certain values in different size vectors

Tags: python, numpy, replace

I got a problem where I cant exchange values in an array. I've got 2 arrays, one filled with *zeros* and *ones*, for example: `disp = [[0.], [0.], [0.], [1.], [1.], [1.], [1.], [0.], [0.], [0.]]` and the other one filled with values I would like to implement at the place where the *ones* are in **disp**, for example: `to_replace_at_1 = [[17.17], [0.], [-7.0] , [7.0]]`.

The result should look like this: `disp = [[0.], [0.], [0.], [17.17], [0.], [-7.0], [7.0], [0.], [0.], [0.]]`.

I tried this:

```
        for i in range(len(disp)):
        vector = disp[i]
        for value in vector:
            if value == 1.0:
                for e in to_replace_at_1:
                    disp[i] = to_replace_at_1[e]
```

But it ends up crashing. What should I try? How do I solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984102/select-elements-of-numpy-array-via-boolean-mask-array may be helpful.

Comment: Are your "arrays" actually NumPy arrays, or are they pure Python lists of lists?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
iterator = iter(to_replace_at_1)
[x if x[0] != 1 else next(iterator) for x in disp]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case it was crashing at `disp[i] = to_replace_at_1[e]` since `e` is a list in your case. Your logic implementation is good tho.

Not the best way I suppose but I can give you a working solution following code.

```
j = 0
for i in range(len(disp)):
    vector = disp[i]
    for value in vector:
        if value == 1.0:
            disp[i] = to_replace_at_1[j]
            j += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do :

```
disp = [[0.], [0.], [0.], [1.], [1.], [1.], [1.], [0.], [0.], [0.]]
to_replace_at_1 = [[17.17], [0.], [-7.0] , [7.0]]

idx = 0

for i, val in enumerate(disp):
    if val[0] == 1.0:
        disp[i] = to_replace_at_1[idx]
        idx += 1


print(disp)
>>> [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [17.17], [0.0], [-7.0], [7.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0]]
```